# Changing onClick attribute with ajax does not fire the new event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

Just tried out the following approach finding that this does not work?

(Using jQuery):

```
function bookmark_add() {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "load.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(msg) {
              var msg_array=msg.split("-");
              var success=msg_array[0];
              var bookmark_id=msg_array[1];

              if(success==1) {
                  $('.btn_bookmark').html('Remove Bookmark');
                   $('.a_bookmark').attr("onClick","bookmark_remove("+bookmark_id+"), return false;");
                  }
              }
        });
    }
```

This function works fine. The attribute of the `<a>` element is being changed correctly. However, the new event (the function `bookmark_remove` is not being fired. So I assume that my approach does not work because of some basic misunderstanding, probably?

Could anyone tell me that this assumption is right and give any hint why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't immediately tell you why it's not working (could be several things; `onClick` should be in all lower case for one thing — the mixed-case version is only okay in HTML *markup* [not XHTML, but HTML], not once you're interacting with the DOM, which is case-sensitive), but there's no reason at all for doing it that way. Instead:

```
$('.a_bookmark').click(function() {
    bookmark_remove(bookmark_id);
    return false;
});
```

If the anchor comes pre-equipped with an existing `onclick` handler, you can clear it like this:

```
$('.a_bookmark').attr("onclick", "");
```

So putting that together:

```
$('.a_bookmark').attr("onclick", "").click(function() {
    bookmark_remove(bookmark_id);
    return false;
});
```

---

Apparently people don't understand where I'm doing that, so here's your full `ajax` call with the change recommended above:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "load.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(msg) {
          var msg_array=msg.split("-");
          var success=msg_array[0];
          var bookmark_id=msg_array[1];

          if(success==1) {
              $('.btn_bookmark').html('Remove Bookmark');
              $('.a_bookmark').attr("onclick", "").click(function() {
                  bookmark_remove(bookmark_id);
                  return false;
              });
          }
    });
```

Comment: If OP currently has an `onclick` attribute bound to add a bookmark, both your listener and his attribute would fire I guess.

Comment: this is wrong, because the bookmark_id value doesn't exist in the .click content

Comment: @WampieDriessen: Yes it does. I'm talking about replacing the code he has in the ajax handler. The click handler will be a closure over the `bookmark_id`.

Comment: ok, so the usual way is still the best way to go.. thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Just don't forget to close quotes after both your `"onclick`. :)

Comment: why is it actually: `$('.a_bookmark').attr("onclick", "")`, why do you use `.attr("onclick", "")`??

Comment: @Chris read my first comment in this answer. TJ is clearing the `onclick` attribute to prevent it from firing together with your new event listener.

Answer (score 2):

```
"bookmark_remove("+bookmark_id+"), return false;"
```

The comma is wrong. it should be a semicolon.

Comment: True. If the OP wanted to use the comma operator, it would need to be `"return bookmark_remove("+bookmark_id+"), false;"` One of many reasons not to over-use the comma operator. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes, Wampie seems to be right, because with a semicolon instead of a comma it works...

Comment: @Chris: Yeah. There are a *lot* of things you can chain together with the comma operator, but you can't put `return` there -- it would have to be at the very beginning, which would be *very* confusing. :-) But better on the whole to use a DOM2 handler via jQuery than do the old DOM0 stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, instead of:

```
$('.a_bookmark').attr("onClick","bookmark_remove("+bookmark_id+"), return false;");
```

I suggest you use this form:

```
$('.a_bookmark').click(function(){
    bookmark_remove(bookmark_id);
    return false;
})
```

more readable with less quotes tokens, right?